# Testing ASP.NET Core full .NET Framework with TestServer gives method not found in vs 2017

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When trying to run test in Visual Studio 2017, all is compiling without issue,
However when I'm trying to create server and client to test:

```
this.Server = new TestServer(
                new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseContentRoot(di.FullName));

 this.Client = this.Server.CreateClient();
```

The `TestServer`is complaining about wrong dependencies (it tries to load version 1.0.0) even if `TestHost` package is:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="1.1.1" />
```

Also test is failing with exception:

```
Cannot find method: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer.CreateClient()'..
```

Comment: RE: the wrong package being loaded--  Make sure that the reference is pointing to the correct version, make sure your csproj doesn't have duplicates, make sure all your references are updated, then delete everything in the solution directory\packages folder except repositories.config.  Then select your solution in solution explorer > right cick > restore packages.  If it still loads the wrong one, uninstall, and re-install the package.

Comment: @Mike_G yeap I've checked all this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is related to wrong test template in VS 2017
manually adding  in  the top  `<PropertyGroup>`

```
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

in `csproj` file fixes issue

Comment: Thanks. This would have take me forever to figure out.

Comment: Yep, needs to be added to the top <PropertyGroup> element, as per this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/926)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim it doesn't need to be in the top it can be in any property group